# SOA-MDS error while compiling an imported jar file

Tags: soa

I see the following error whenever I try to compile my SOA composite. I exported the jar file SOA EM and imported into my project. This was working fine untill few days ago.

I have checked the MDS connection and the file is present in that location.

We are using SOA 12.1.3 version for this and DB based MDS. Is there a work around for this?

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<markers xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/jdeveloper/110000ide-markers">
   <list n="markers">
      <hash>
         <value n="#_buffer_version" v="0"/>
         <value n="code" v="1"/>
         <value n="column" v="243"/>
         <value n="description" v="Error(5,243): Load of wsdl &quot;oramds:/apps/MetaData/Components/EnterpriseBusinessServiceLibrary/otc/EBO/EPOntSalesOrderInboundBPEL/v1/EPOntSalesOrderInboundBPEL.wsdl&quot; failed"/>
         <list n="events">
            <hash>
               <value n="event-description" v="Build"/>
               <value n="event-id" v="da6e8e32-7adb-438f-b6a8-122a2a62ebb1"/>
               <value n="event-timestamp" v="1544639113651"/>
            </hash>
         </list>
         <value n="id" v="dcd9ba9f-8409-4a7d-ae35-e3bc0ff17a01"/>
         <value n="lastUpdated" v="1544639124049"/>
         <value n="length" v="0"/>
         <value n="line" v="5"/>
         <url n="markableURL" path="../../../JDeveloper/mywork/SOACOMCluster1/EDI850prd2/SOA/composite.xml"/>
         <value n="offset" v="926"/>
         <value n="severity" v="0"/>
         <value n="timestamp" v="1544639123941"/>
         <value n="type" v="oracle.jdeveloper.compiler.CompilerProblemMarker"/>
      </hash>
   </list>
</markers>
```